# SquishIt javascript error when minimized: 'missing ; before statement'

Tags: javascript, squishit

When I run SquishIt in development mode everything works fine. When I put it into production mode I am getting the 'missing ; before statement' error in Javascript. I've tried removing the offending javascipt files, but the error moves down to the next one.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this problem on the Squishit [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/squishit/browse_thread/thread/ff81b817dea932ad#). Justin reponded:

> This is a known bug that is going to
>   be fixed in an soon to be released
>   SquishIt 0.6.1. Essentially the ajax
>   minifier is compressing the files
>   separately before we are combining
>   them into one. This can cause the
>   issue you are seeing. The fix in the
>   meantime is to use the WithCompressor
>   option and switch to something like
>   the YUI compressor temporarily.the YUI compressor temporarily.

```
Bundle.JavaScript()
.Add("/Scripts/Frameworks/jquery.js").WithMinifier(JavaScriptMinifiers.Yui)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you're missing a ; somewhere in your code that's being [automatically inserted by the browser](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).  Use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to find the offending lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about that, so I added a file at a time. Each file past the first one would cause that error.

Thanks for the jsLint link.